# How to achieve a 'rollout' effect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Look at this guys blog:

http://simplebits.com

I really like the animation effect when you mouseover the 'infinity' symbol to the left of posts - it rolls out a shortened URL for the post. I'm trying to figure out how to adapt/mimic this (I want to have the email symbol as an image and roll out my email address when its hovered over).

I'm relatively new to jQuery (which I'm assuming this effect is done with). Any idea how I could go about this?

Comment: Same effect can be done using CSS3 transitions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @AshentePaul said you can do it with CSS3...
But if you really want to do with jQuery take a look in [jQuery.fn.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function..

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/u8MS3/)

```
var $col = $("#collapse"),
    $example = $("#example");

$example.hover(
    function(){
        $example.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 400, "linear");
        $col.stop().animate({ width: "200px" }, 400, "linear");
    },
    function(){
        $example.stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 400, "linear");        
        $col.stop().animate({ width: "0" }, 400, "linear");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick example:

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zT9Y8/7/)

I applied 0 width by default and on hover `width: auto` or in my case 300px :p Opacity, color can be set just by adding default style to a low value and the hover state to max or higher :p Vice-versa works also.

```
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
-o-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
transition: all .5s ease .05s
```

Have fun.

Comment: Recommend you change the CSS selector from `span:hover + i` to `div:hover i`, so you can hover over the flyout without it retracting. (See: http://jsfiddle.net/zT9Y8/8/)

Comment: Voted up as this is an equally valid approach to jQuery. Many thanks!